# MVC : PHP Laravel Vs Asp.NET

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, laravel

I am starting to build an E learning platform, Application will be expected to cater whole amount of user , there would be some automated jobs, and the vast range of learning material to be stored on server. moreover i will also be dealing with APIs & third party Library.

I am a bit confuse in selection of framework, to build, with having two different Options i.e. PHP Laravel & ASP.NET MVC. I also had research on internet regarding the pros and cons of Both but the major Criteria are :

- Performance
- License. (Open Source or PAID)
- flexibility (easily maintainable)
  -

Would Laravel make a better choice given the nature of our workflow in the circumstances?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This may be interesting for you: http://forums.asp.net/t/1933303.aspx?Is+ASP+NET+Dead+

Comment: Just download [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) and forget about writing your own system -- Moodle is a well-established e-learning platform written in PHP. No point re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 9):

I think that this is not the correct question. PHP and ASP.NET provide good performance and can be flexible. It is depend on you when selecting. Good code can cover any issue. Focus on your programing techniques and developing your code will result in good outcome regardless of the framework you use.